# How to test react component using jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, jsx

I am getting `SyntaxError: /test/ut/client/breadcrumbs/BreadCrumbs.ut.test.js: Unexpected token (12:6)` error. Code is given below. And the code coverage is 0% because test suits failed.

I am using `jest v-"^24.8.0"`, `jest-dom v-"^3.5.0"`, `jest-junit v-"^6.4.0"`

```
describe("BreadCrumbs", () => {
  afterEach(cleanup);
  test("Should render breadcrumbs on usecase page", () => {
    const useCaseBreadCrumbs = create(
      <BreadCrumbs
        list={USECASE_BREADCRUMBS.list}
        disabledLabel={USECASE_BREADCRUMBS.disabledLink}
      />
    );
    console.log(useCaseBreadCrumbs);
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

[image: Screenshot is given below]

Comment: Did you import `react` at the top of the page to use `jsx`? ;)

Comment: Also a heads up, `expect(tree)...`, `tree` has not been defined, this should be `useCaseBreadCrumbs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `import React from "react";` on top